# Closure in JS with parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, closures

I have an Object like this

```
JSON_DATA = {
    "EVENT" : "data/sequence/sequenceEvent.json",
    "CHAT" : "data/sequence/sequenceChat.json",
}
```

I would like to load those value so I do this

```
LoadJSON(JSON_DATA, function(data){
    var DATA = data;
});

function LoadJSON(jsons, callback){
    var counterLoaded = 0;
    var counterToLoad = Object.keys(jsons).length;

    var parsedData = {};
    for(var key in jsons){
        ajax.get(jsons[key], "", function(data){
            parsedData[key] = JSON.parse(data);
            counterLoaded++;
            if(counterLoaded == counterToLoad){
                callback(parsedData);
            }

        }, true)
    }
}
```

Now, has I know I have a closure problem, like key is always the last one.

But, I searched on the internet, and expect a setTimeOut OR a function like this

```
function LoadJSON(jsons, callback){
    var counterLoaded = 0;
    var counterToLoad = Object.keys(jsons).length;

    var parsedData = {};
    for(var key in jsons){
        ajax.get(jsons[key], "", (function(key){
            parsedData[key] = JSON.parse(data);
            counterLoaded++;
            if(counterLoaded == counterToLoad){
                callback(parsedData);
            }

        })(key), true)
    }
}
```

It would not work, but in my problem, I need to pass also the parameter data.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Do you want to perform the `get`s in parallel, or in serial?

Comment: I m sorry I don't know what you mean, What I would like is just to have in the end in LoadJSON something like this var DATA = {key1 : obj1parsed, key2 : object2parsed}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> key is always the last one.

Option 1: using closures.

```
for (var key in jsons) {
  (function(k) {
    ajax.get(jsons[k], "", function(data) {
      parsedData[k] = JSON.parse(data);
      counterLoaded++;
      if (counterLoaded == counterToLoad) {
        callback(parsedData);
      }
    }, true);
  })(key);
}
```

Option 2: using Promise API.

Comment: OMG I am so stupid.. I knew I had to do this, but I did on the wrong function... thanks --